# Remember hidden rows after data refresh in Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying to do the following using c# code:

1. Hide some rows in excel.
2. Clear all data and formats in excel sheet.
3. Put other data to excel sheet.

I would like the hidden rows still remain hidden. 
Is it possible?

Thank You!

Comment: Hidden would remain hidden...Yes...but what about the data in hidden rows? Would you want to preserve them? because when you clear all data & format the data for the hidden rows is also gone..is it fine?

Comment: I need to clear the data in hidden cells as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample code that can get you going....

```
        //Create an Excel App
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet;

        //Open a Workbook
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"d:\test.xlsx");
        xlWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

        //My Workbook contains 10 rows with some data and formatting
        //I Hide rows 3, 4 & 5
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range hiddenRange = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A3:C5");
        hiddenRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;

        //Get the entire sheet and Clear everything on it including data & formatting
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range allRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        allRange.Clear();


        //Now Add some new data, say a Title on the first cell, and some more data in a loop later
        xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Title";

        for (int i = 6; i < 10; i++)
        {
            xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1] = i.ToString();
        }

        xlApp.Visible = true;
```

Thats it....

Answer (score 3):

I've had great results using [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to manipulate excel spreadsheets.

While I haven't tried your case I've done similar things. In my case I put my private data into a new worksheet and hide that, which ClodedXML made simple.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a variable and hide them again after you have populated excel with data.

Comment: I will need to to it if there will not be another solution, by the way can you publish please how to do it, because I didnt succeed , I succeed to get all the hidden columns but I do not know how to get the column name from the range object.